# What's the limit of $\tan x$ when $x$ aproaches $\pi /2$ by the left?

Tags: calculus, limits

To be more specific:

$$\lim_{x\to (\pi/2)^-} \tan x$$

Thanks :)

Comment: So, taking que the limit I get 1/0 but it can't be zero. I know by the graph that it aproaches infinite but I don't know why

Comment: If you need to add information on your question, please [edit] it instead of adding a comment.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Write $\tan(x) = \dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and then take the limit: $$\lim_{x\to \large \frac \pi 2\,^-} \dfrac {\sin x}{\cos x}$$

The numerator approaches $1$ and the denominator approaches $0$, when $x$ is approaching $\pi/2$ from the left. So the limit is $...\,?$